# Setting images in gridview to transparent

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

So I have images in gridview. These images are shown in an activity. When one of the images is clicked, new activity is started with this image. In this activity, If user inputs correct answer, new activity is started that indicates the answer is correct. After user inputs correct answer, I want to set this image more transparent with a check mark in gridwiew. If the user clicks again to this correct view, I want to show same activity which indicates it was solved correct. How can I do that?

Here is my activity which contains grid view:

```
public class LogoSelectionActivity extends Activity {
.
.
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra ("clicked_position", position);
             startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is my activity where user enter inputs:

```
public class LogoActivity extends Activity{

EditText text;
Button check;
Boolean a;
int id;
Names name;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check_button);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageView incorrect = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.incorrect);
    switch (getIntent().getIntExtra ("clicked_position", -1))
    {
      case 0:
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.adese);
        id = R.drawable.adese;
        break;
      case 1:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.birvar);
         id = R.drawable.birvar;
         break;
      case 2:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.agaoglu);
         break;
      case 3:
          view.setImageResource(R.drawable.akinsoft);
          break;
      default:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.afra);
         id = R.drawable.afra;
    }
    name = Names.forDrawable(id);
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            a=name.isCorrect(text.getText().toString());
            if(a==true){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, CorrectActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                incorrect.setVisibility(0);
                incorrect.setVisibility(4);
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope I could explain my intention clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of ways to do this. Because this is not problem this is functionality that you want in your project.

According to my logic I am giving you one solution.

Steps:

1. Create one static array with the length of your items in grid view with default value is 0.

   ```
    static int[] items = {0,0,0,...};
   ```
2. Now check in `getView` methode of grid view with the value according to position in array that if it is 0 then it will looks like normal otherwise it will look with different (Here you want transparent with check box this will you get by adding one more image on it.)

   ```
   If(items[position] == 0){

   }else{

   }
   ```
3. Now when user taps any image and navigate to other screen (Suppose Activity B) that time pass value of that position from that array and check in Activity B's `OnCreate()`.

   ```
   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra ("clicked_position", position);
        intent.putExtra ("answered_or_not", items[position]);

        startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
4. And if answered means if its value is 1 then show accordingly other wise as it is.
5. And when it user give answer unanswered question make its value 1 in that array.

I hope it will help you can ask if any question.

Comment: It seems to work. I tried with a little example. If I encounter problems when I construct the whole code, I will ask you again if it is ok with you. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I clicked answered view, I get activity which indicates that is correct. It works fine. However, if i close the app and reopen it again, all of them are reseted and begin with default. How can I do it permanently?

Comment: ohh For that you have to option (1) Shared preferences and (2) save in Database.